# OSX Terminal: FTP upload only if file size different

Tags: macos, terminal, ftp, diff, filezilla

I am currently using FileZilla to backup my Documents.

The manual procedure for this is as follows:

- Sign in to FTP using username and password
- Open Documents folder on FTP site
- Drag documents from Mac into Documents folder on FTP site
- Choose option to 'Only upload if source file is a different size'

Would it be possible to automate this process using the Mac OSX Terminal?